# Probability with statistics using 'R'

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I've been going through a few previous exam questions and came across this one and computed in the programing 'R'.

```
Let X ∼ N (5, 1^2). P ((X ≤ 3) ∪ (X > 6))


> mean <- 5
> sd <-1
> pnorm(6,mean,sd) - pnorm(3,mean,sd)
[1] 0.8185946
```

I think I may have gone wrong somewhere or be missing an additional computation.

Could anyone with **experience** with R double check my calculation?

Comment: You've calculated the probability that $3\leq X\leq 6$.

Comment: @Arthur how do you do >6?

Comment: @Zen, all you want is 1 minus your current answer.

Comment: 1-0.8185946, or if you want to do it from the start just 1-(pnorm(6,mean,sd)-pnorm(3,mean,sd)).